# Feeding large numpy arrays into TensorFlow estimators via tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

TensorFlow's [`tf.data.Dataset` documentation on consuming numpy arrays](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays) states that in order to use numpy arrays in combination with the `Dataset` API, the arrays have to be small enough (<2 GB in total) to be used as tensors, or they can be fed into the dataset via placeholders.

However, if you use `Dataset` in conjunction with estimators (where placeholders are not available), the documentation does not provide a solution on working with large arrays without placeholders.

Are there other options for passing placeholder values into estimators that can be used or is the solution to provide the data in `tfrecord` or `csv` format?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.split` and `from_generator` prior to creating dataset object.

```
chunks = list(np.split(array, 1000))

def gen():
    for i in chunks:
        yield i

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, tf.float32)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer_size)
...
```

You can control the size of dataset with shuffle. It will load only specified quantity at a time.

Comment: I have been using `from_generator` so far. My main issue with it is that after you exhaust the dataset iterator and it repeats itself, the generator code is called again. Because the data needs some extensive preprocessing, calling the generator over and over throughout the model results in significant slowdown every 200-300 steps.